# Dois id em tabela hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Há possibilidade de dois campos ser id em uma tabela do hibernate? Tenho duas ids que precisa ser unica em par na tabela. Mas não sei como implementar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem como fazer utilizando @EmbeddedId

Você pode fazer assim:

```
@Embeddable
class ClassePrimeira implements Serializable {

@Id
Integer chaveUm;
@Id
Integer chaveDois;

// get’s e set’s  

}

@Entity
public class Classe {

@EmbeddedId
private ClassePrimeira id;
// get’s e set’s  
}
```

> Anotação **@Id**, **@IdClass**, ou **@EmbeddedId** para Chaves Compostas: Quando
>   uma chave primária consiste de múltiplas colunas, precisamos de uma
>   estratégia diferente para agrupa-las de forma que possamos permitir
>   que a ferramenta de persistência manipule valores de chaves como um
>   único objeto. Dessa forma, precisamos criar uma classe que represente
>   essa chave-primária. Essa classe como regra geral deve ser pública,
>   deve ter um construtor default, deve ser serializável, e deve
>   implementar os métodos hashCode() e equals() que permite ao Hibernate
>   testar colisões nas chaves primárias.

Fonte: https://www.devmedia.com.br/mapeamento-no-hibernate-com-anotacoes/29472

Apesar de acima mostrar o básico de como declarar duas id's em um mesmo modelo, você pode entrar na documentação do hibernate: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-id, e apesar de estar em inglês no item 5.1.2.1 tem uma boa explicação para o que você quer fazer.

Comment: Gostei da resposta! +1.. Só não entendi uma coisa: o Hibernate testa colisão de chaves primárias? Nossa! Isso deve ser **muito** lento

Comment: Eu ainda não precisei trabalhar com chaves compostas, mas se levarmos em consideração que em uma chave simples o método equals() e hashCode() testa somente uma chave, e que em caso de ser necessário ter que usar várias chaves compostas, o correto é testar todas as chaves com certeza a verificação é bem mais lenta.